# How to rebase huge number of commits

Tags: git, rebase

I am trying to sync my fork with upstream.

```
git rebase upstream/master
```

But sadly, I found that there are 100+ of my local commits, and every one of them need manually conflict solving.

One of idea I am thinking is I can squash all local commits into one, then rebasing only one commit will be easier. But this is the last thing I want since I really want to keep all my commits' records.

Is there anyway to rebase huge commits with less effort?

Comment: How on earth did you manage that? Where did local and remote come unsynced? Have you tried a pull rebase?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using `git rebase` as opposed to `git pull` (i.e. `git pull upstream/master`)? The latter will produce a history with two branches, but it will only try to merge the last commits upstream and on your local workspace, meaning that you'll only need to resolve commits once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a merge is actually what you want here, not a rebase. Resolving the merge conflicts will be equivalent to what you would see if you squashed all 100+ commits to a single commit, and then rebased that commit. But with the merge, you will preserve your work-in-progress history, as you desire.

Rebase is nice when you have just a few commits to sync-up with the latest work from your peers, or have a specific need to rewrite history, but when you have diverged by 100+ commits, you've created a use case that would more commonly be handled with a branch. Syncing up via a merge commit I think makes perfect sense in this case.

If you *really* need to be the only one to whom your work-in-progress history is visible, you could create a local branch (`git branch <my-true-local-history>`) pointed at the head of your local work-in-progress to preserve a named reference to the commit, and then perform a squash merge (`git merge --squash`) which will still create a merge commit, but will collapse your work-in-progress commits down to a single commit (the local branch you created earlier will still point to the true detailed history, however).

Answer (score 1):

Scenario:
I created a new repository, and I had around a hundred commit messages on the first new branch. To keep the history clean, I wanted to squash everything into a single commit before merging.

Solution:

1. Create new branch from `main`|`master`.  (Currently only has the init commit)

`git checkout -b feature/<name_of_new_branch>`

2. Switch to the new branch (<feature/<name_of_new_branch)

`git checkout <feature/<name_of_new_branch>`

3. Merge and squash branch with many commits.

`git merge --squash feature/<branch_with_many_commits`

4. Commit changes with a single new message.

`git commit -m "Your new commit message"`

5. Finally, push your changes.
   `git push`